# Trouble with iOS Facebook's completionHandler block

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, objective-c-blocks

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"/me/friendlists" 
                                                               parameters:@{ @"fields": @"name",} 
                                                               HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    if (!error)
        jsonArr1 = [result objectForKey:@"data"];

        //Inside the block
        for(int i=0; i<5; ++i)
            NSLog(@"%@", [[jsonArr1 objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"name"]); //works fine
}]

//Outside the block
for(int i=0; i<5; ++i)
    NSLog(@"%@", [[jsonArr1 objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"name"]); //gives out (null)
```

I've found that the blocks are called asynchronously, which means the block is called only after the outer for loop is executed, which is why it's giving null outside the block and is outputting fine inside the block.

Is there any workaround to use the `jsonArr1` outside the block? I want to use that array in UITableView's `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Can someone please help? There are no latest tutorials on the net for integrating Fb into iOS.

Comment: have you tried debugging it? Set a breakpoint, inspect `error`, `result` and `jsonArr1`.

Comment: @luk2302 I've slightly edited the code. Please go through it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole point of asynchronous execution is that you call a method with a completion handler, the method returns immediately while scheduling the real work to be done on some other queue than the one it was called on and the callback handler is called **once the method's work is done and the results are ready for you to process**.

So, process the data in your completion handler.   And if you need to update UI, then do something like:

```
[someFaceThingy doSomethingHere:@"/path/user/bobdobbs" completionHandler:^(NSDictionary *results, NSError *error ){
    if (!results) { .... process error and return ....}
    ... process results ...
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        ... apply results to table view ...
    });
}];

... don't process anything here because there'll be nothing to process ...
```

Comment: Do I have to learn threading and GCD stuff now or can I bypass it for now to get things done?

Comment: @Viki If you are using an asynchronous API, you are doing threading.  If you don't learn how to correctly manage concurrency with said API, you're very likely to be spending a **huge** amount of time trying to debug mind-bendingly confusing crashes and unexpected behaviors.

Comment: Then I will go through the respective programming guides. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Can you please list out a few popular asynchronous APIs you know? It would be very helpful

Comment: @Viki Just about any method that takes a completion handler will be executing code concurrently prior to calling the handler.  The handler is oft called in a random queue and, thus, your handler needs to be concurrency safe, too.   All of CoreData's API is built around concurrency.  As well, the entire CoreAnimation integration into UIKit is built on concurrency and you'll quickly need to account for that as you as your needs grow.

Comment: @Viki In short; if you want an application to remain responsive to the user, you need to get all of your heavy work off of the main queue.  And that requires concurrency in that you'll need to update the UI with the results of that work.

Comment: Any good links you might suggest me to read other than official PGs? :)
You seem quite well versed with this blocks and threads stuff! :p

Comment: I'd start here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html  (which is an official guide, but a good one) and then branch out from there on the specific APIs that you want to use.  (not exactly what you asked for, but I'm not well versed in the publications available).

Comment: I said other than the official programming guides right? Nevertheless, thanks! :)

Comment: @viki Here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/135709/what-are-the-best-resources-for-learning-about-concurrency-and-multi-threaded-ap

Comment: Done learning Threading and GCD from the official programming guides. Now your code makes sense to me, Not to mention this technology is quite great!

Answer (score 0):

```
    Is this correct?
    I did the way just you said but still it isn't working out!

     -(void) viewDidLoad
    {
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

    dispatch_queue_t aQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

    dispatch_async(aQueue, ^{ 
    jsonArr = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
    for(int i=0; i<[jsonArr  count]; ++i)
    {
    [ultimateArr addObject:[[jsonArr objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"name"]]; 
         //Don't know why but objects are not being added to the ultimateArr

    NSLog(@"%@", [[jsonArr objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"name"]);
}
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
[myTableView reloadData];
                        });

                });

            }];

        }
```

Comment: OK -- you really don't want to be loading stuff in a tableView: data loading delegate method.   The general flow is 1. tell your app to go load something.  2. Do code like the above (but not in the table view method) to go load some stuff  3. When done, tell the main thread to -reloadData on the table view.   The tableView will then pull the freshly loaded data via the tableviewdatasource methods.